# How does a smartwatch detect the worn handedness?

Tags: wearables

**How does a smartwatch detect the worn handedness?**

I have googled, but I could not find any valuable information on the query. What is/are the hardware(s) and/or algorithm(s) smartwatches use to detect on which hand the user is wearing the device?

Comment: Which smart watches do this? Apparently the Apple watch for instance relies on a manual setting.

Comment: it could use motion detection

Comment: @jsotola I didn't believe it should be strict to single algorithm. Could you describe detail about motion detection used for handedness detection?

Comment: about the motion detection ... think about the motion of your left wrist as you go about your daily activities ... compare it to the motion of your right wrist

Comment: @jsotola I updated the post as it confused you. About the motion sensor, could you please confirm if there is any article or paper or patent on this regards? Thanks

Comment: i cannot confim that ... i was only describing how I would do it ... i would have to do internet search for articles and patents ... I would probably come up emptyhanded like you did, when you did your research ... my guess is that the watch contains a gesture engine of some type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a 3 axis accelerometer in the watch, if the gravity vector is predominantly pointing at the right hand edge of the watch, it's on the left wrist and vice versa.